# Why rebooting the system takes longer than a shutdown in fedora?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, shutdown

I'm a fedora (19/ x86-64) user. When I power off the system, it always takes about 3 to 4 seconds to shut down. But whenever I reboot the system, it takes the system much longer (about 30 seconds or more) to power off (and then it starts again).

I suppose that the process of a *power off*, **till the point of termination of the operating system and powering off**, is exactly equivalent to a reboot and the differences start after that point, where in the case of a reboot, system boots again. So why a *reboot* takes longer to power off the system than a *power off*?

Comment: Do you see the shutdown messages scrolling over the screen or is this disabled? If so, do you see one process taking longer to shutdown in `reboot` than `shutdown`?

Comment: No, I just see the fedora logo when rebooting/powering off. I guess I can get into that *text mode* by hitting escape or something (not sure); but how can I set it to do so automatically from the beginning of the process?

Comment: `ESC` will work for this instance (for debugging shutdown). Others have suggested for permanent display of messages replacing `rhgb quiet` with `vga=791` in `grub.conf`. (there are other methods)